How to implement search bar in column filter for QTableWidget in Pyqt5 Python?
I have a created a QTableWidget using pyqt5 and managed to add filter option in each column of the table widget successfully with one of the answers available on stack overflow. filters works as expected but I wanted to add search bar in the filter at the top to search for the values.
In my python script I would probably have around more than 50 unique values in filter. So it becomes easy if there's a way to search for a value in the filter.
Also, Is there a way we can add scroll bar in this because currently if I add more values to the table, my filter area gets bigger and bigger to accumulate all values.
Here is My complete python code :
import csv
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidget, QCheckBox, QWidgetAction, QMenu, QDialogButtonBox, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.filterall = QTableWidget(self)
        self.filterall.setColumnCount(0)
        self.filterall.setRowCount(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.filterall)

        self.loadAll()
        self.horizontalHeader = self.filterall.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)
        self.keywords = dict([(i, []) for i in range(self.filterall.columnCount())])
        self.checkBoxs = []
        self.col = None

    def slotSelect(self, state):

        for checkbox in self.checkBoxs:
            checkbox.setChecked(QtCore.Qt.Checked == state)

    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, index):
        #self.clearFilter()
        self.menu = QMenu(self)
        #self.menu.setStyleSheet('QMenu { menu-scrollable: true; }')
        self.col = index

        data_unique = []

        self.checkBoxs = []

        checkBox = QCheckBox("Select all", self.menu)
        checkableAction = QWidgetAction(self.menu)
        checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(checkBox)
        self.menu.addAction(checkableAction)
        checkBox.setChecked(True)
        checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.slotSelect)

        for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount()):
            if not self.filterall.isRowHidden(i):
                item = self.filterall.item(i, index)
                font = QFont()
                font.setBold(False)
                self.filterall.horizontalHeaderItem(index).setFont(font)
                if item.text() not in data_unique:
                    data_unique.append(item.text())
                    checkBox = QCheckBox(item.text(), self.menu)
                    checkBox.setChecked(True)
                    checkableAction = QWidgetAction(self.menu)
                    checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(checkBox)
                    self.menu.addAction(checkableAction)
                    self.checkBoxs.append(checkBox)

        btn = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel,
                                     QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self.menu)
        btn.accepted.connect(self.menuClose)
        btn.rejected.connect(self.menu.close)
        checkableAction = QWidgetAction(self.menu)
        checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(btn)
        self.menu.addAction(checkableAction)

        headerPos = self.filterall.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())

        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(index)
        self.menu.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    def menuClose(self):
        self.keywords[self.col] = []
        for element in self.checkBoxs:
            if element.isChecked():
                self.keywords[self.col].append(element.text())
        self.filterdata()
        self.menu.close()

    def loadAll(self):
        with open("sample.csv", "r") as inpfil:
            reader = csv.reader(inpfil, delimiter=',')
            csheader = next(reader)
            ncol = len(csheader)
            data = list(reader)
            row_count = len(data)

            self.filterall.setRowCount(row_count)
            self.filterall.setColumnCount(ncol)
            self.filterall.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(str('%s' % ', '.join(map(str, csheader))).split(","))

            for ii in range(0, row_count):
                mainins = data[ii]
                for var in range(0, ncol):
                    self.filterall.setItem(ii, var, QTableWidgetItem(mainins[var]))

    def clearFilter(self):
        for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount()):
            self.filterall.setRowHidden(i, False)

    def filterdata(self):

        columnsShow = dict([(i, True) for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount())])
        
        for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.filterall.columnCount()):
                item = self.filterall.item(i, j)
                if self.keywords[j]:
                    if item.text() not in self.keywords[j]:
                        columnsShow[i] = False
                        font = QFont()
                        font.setBold(True)
                        self.filterall.horizontalHeaderItem(j).setFont(font)
                        
        for key, value in columnsShow.items():
            self.filterall.setRowHidden(key, not value)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Widget()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())


I would to see my code working such that when user type in searchbar, it filters option from the given unique values. It is like having search bar in excel filters where you can type keyword and filter available unique values.
Expected Sample Output :

My code filtering as shown below :

My sample.csv file has data (19 records) as this shown in below screenshot:


Menu cannot be made scrollable (at least, not easily and reliably). You should consider another approach, such as a QWidget with the Popup window flag, containing a QListView with the filters, which is probably more appropriate than creating a context menu that actually doesn't behave nor look like an actual menu.

@musicamante Ok, I got your point about scrollable Menu. Is there a way to add search with these unique column values in the above python code so that the value I put into search box can be filter from the options of unique values, similar to excel like filtering.

Here is a revision of your code with a search bar implemented when filtering:
import csv
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidget, QCheckBox, QWidgetAction, QMenu, QDialogButtonBox, QTableWidgetItem, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.filterall = QTableWidget(self)
        self.filterall.setColumnCount(0)
        self.filterall.setRowCount(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.filterall)
        self.loadAll()
        self.horizontalHeader = self.filterall.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)
        self.keywords = dict([(i, []) for i in range(self.filterall.columnCount())])
        self.checkBoxs = []
        self.col = None

    def slotSelect(self, state):
        for checkbox in self.checkBoxs:
            checkbox.setChecked(QtCore.Qt.Checked == state)

    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, index):
        self.clearFilter()
        self.menu = QMenu(self)
        self.col = index
        data_unique = []
        self.checkBoxs = []
        self.search_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.search_bar.setPlaceholderText("Search...")
        self.search_bar.textChanged.connect(self.on_search)
        search_action = QWidgetAction(self.menu)
        search_action.setDefaultWidget(self.search_bar)
        self.menu.addAction(search_action)
        checkBox = QCheckBox("Select all", self.menu)
        checkableAction = QWidgetAction(self.menu)
        checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(checkBox)
        self.menu.addAction(checkableAction)
        checkBox.setChecked(True)
        checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.slotSelect)
        for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount()):
            if not self.filterall.isRowHidden(i):
                item = self.filterall.item(i, index)
                if item.text() not in data_unique:
                    data_unique.append(item.text())
                    checkBox = QCheckBox(item.text(), self.menu)
                    checkBox.setChecked(True)
                    checkableAction = QWidgetAction(self.menu)
                    checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(checkBox)
                    self.menu.addAction(checkableAction)
                    self.checkBoxs.append(checkBox)
        btn = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel,
                                     QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self.menu)
        btn.accepted.connect(self.menuClose)
        btn.rejected.connect(self.menu.close)
        checkableAction = QWidgetAction(self.menu)
        checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(btn)
        self.menu.addAction(checkableAction)
        headerPos = self.filterall.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())
        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(index)
        self.menu.setFixedWidth(self.menu.sizeHint().width())
        self.search_bar.setFixedWidth(self.menu.width() - 20) 
        self.menu.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    def on_search(self, text):
        for action in self.menu.actions():
            if isinstance(action, QWidgetAction):
                widget = action.defaultWidget()
                if isinstance(widget, QCheckBox) and widget.text() != "Select all":
                    if text.lower() in widget.text().lower():
                        action.setVisible(True)
                    else:
                        action.setVisible(False)

    def menuClose(self):
        self.keywords[self.col] = []
        for element in self.checkBoxs:
            if element.isChecked():
                self.keywords[self.col].append(element.text())
        self.filterdata()
        self.menu.close()

    def loadAll(self):
        with open("sample.csv", "r") as inpfil:
            reader = csv.reader(inpfil, delimiter=',')
            csheader = next(reader)
            ncol = len(csheader)
            data = list(reader)
            row_count = len(data)
            self.filterall.setRowCount(row_count)
            self.filterall.setColumnCount(ncol)
            self.filterall.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(str('%s' % ', '.join(map(str, csheader))).split(","))
            for ii in range(0, row_count):
                mainins = data[ii]
                for var in range(0, ncol):
                    self.filterall.setItem(ii, var, QTableWidgetItem(mainins[var]))

    def clearFilter(self):
        for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount()):
            self.filterall.setRowHidden(i, False)

    def filterdata(self):
        columnsShow = dict([(i, True) for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount())])
        for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.filterall.columnCount()):
                item = self.filterall.item(i, j)
                if self.keywords[j]:
                    if item.text() not in self.keywords[j]:
                        columnsShow[i] = False
                        font = QFont()
                        font.setBold(True)
                        self.filterall.horizontalHeaderItem(j).setFont(font)        
        for key, value in columnsShow.items():
            self.filterall.setRowHidden(key, not value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

